# Catchable fatal error: Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string

Tags: php, nclob

I have return some code, which returns clob data from database and here I'm trying to display it in front end and ended up in getting some error.

Below is my function which returns data

```
Function tabledetails() {

    $sql = "my_query";

    $std = oci_parse($conn, $sql) ;

    oci_execute($std) ;

    While(oci_fetch($std)) {

        $sdeQuery = oci_result($std, 'attribute_name') ;

    }

    return array($sdeQuery) ;

}
```

In front end

```
$tb = tabledetails() ;
echo $tb[0];
```

What I have missed in this.  Thanks in advance

Comment: `var_dump($tb);` it's probably an object.

Comment: And FYI you're only getting one from the function even if there are multiple.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes that function returning more than one value,  just for understanding I'm returning only one value

Comment: array(3)  {[0]=>NULL [1] => object (OCI-Lob)#1 (1) {["descriptor "]=>resource(25) of type(oci8 descriptor)} [2]=>string(15)  " Insert new rows"} This is the error I'm getting after adding var_dump($tb) ;

Comment: I don't know oci functions but `echo $tb[2];` maybe

Comment: It's returning $tb[2] value.  Issue is with $tb[0] and $tb[1]

Comment: 0 is NULL and 1 is an object with a resource property which can't be echoed.

Comment: @AbraCadaver is there any way to display it

Comment: It's not database data.  You need to explain what you want to do exactly.

Comment: We have one field which has 4k + character and I'm trying to display it in front end.